# Migrating from ASP.NET CORE 3.0 to 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to migrate my project from asp.net core 3.0 to 3.1 and I have found one issue:

```
public static bool CheckConnection(this DataContext dataContext)
    {
        try
        {
            return dataContext.Database.CanConnect();
        }
        catch(SqlException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

this code worked in version 3.0, but when I have migrated I got this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
> Message=The database provider attempted to register an implementation of the 'IRelationalTypeMappingSource' service. This is not a service defined by EF and as such must be registered as a provider-specific service using the 'TryAddProviderSpecificServices' method.
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
> StackTrace:
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.GetServiceCharacteristics(Type serviceType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.TryAdd(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.TryAddTService,TImplementation
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SqlServerServiceCollectionExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Infrastructure.Internal.SqlServerOptionsExtension.ApplyServices(IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.ApplyServices(IDbContextOptions options, ServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.g__BuildServiceProvider|3()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__2(Int64 k)
> at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ServiceProviderCache.GetOrAdd(IDbContextOptions options, Boolean providerRequired)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_Dependencies()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.CanConnect()
> at FooBar.AppCore.DbSetExtension.CheckConnection(DataContext dataContext) in D:\Work\FooBar\FooBar\AppCore\DbSetExtension.cs:line 331
> at FooBar.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in D:\Work\FooBar\FooBar\Startup.cs:line 68
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
> at FooBar.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Work\FooBar\FooBar\Program.cs:line 17

Am I missing something or it is common problem and I have to change my code?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1441.

Comment: Which version of EntityFrameworkCore are you using? And, where you are using/calling the CheckConnection method? According to the error message, it seems that you are using SQL server database, I have checked your code (remove the `static` and `this` key words) in an Asp.net core MVC application (using the EF core 3.1.7 version), the code works well on my side.

Comment: @jeroenh has right - one entityFrameworkCore was updated to pre-release version (5.0) and the rest was 3.1.8. Now it works properly with the same version of all packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated in [this github issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1441), this can occur when you have different versions of EF Core in your project. Verify that all projects in your solution refer to the same version of EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is LinqKit v 5.0.20 that had a dependency on EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.0-rc.2.20475.6.
Updating the version to the previous one solved the issue:
`<PackageReference Include="LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.20" />`